# Correct error handling of nested async functions with promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

Let's take this example async function, `asyncFunction`, which takes a Boolean parameter `res`. if `res` is true, the promise will resolve with the string "success". if `res` is false, the promise will reject with an error object containing the string "success".

```
const asyncFunction = (res) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (res) return resolve("Success");
      return reject(new Error("Error"));
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

I am calling `asyncFunction` from the function `innerFunction` when uses a try-catch block. So far so good.

```
const innerFunction = async () => {
  try {
    return await asyncFunction(false); //Will reject
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("caught error inside innerFunction");
    return error;
  }
};
```

In `outerFunction`, I'm executing

```
const outerFunction = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await innerFunction();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("caught error inside outerFunction");
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Finally, I'm running outer function.

```
outerFunction();
```

I expected both catch blocks to catch the error and I was wrong.
I guess that you can't catch the same exception twice? I'm not sure but my guess is that the Error object, behind the scenes, gets flagged as a "handled" error and therefore does not get recognized as one in `outerFunction`. (I would love some insight on this!)

My solution is to throw a new error in innerFunction:

```
const innerFunction = async () => {
  try {
    return await asyncFunction(false); //Will reject
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("caught error inside innerFunction");
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

I apologize for the length, but finally, my question is: is this a "correct" way of handling a situation where I must handle the error in `outerFunction`? Is there any "better" way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot catch same error twice. The method of relaying error will be buggy. instead what I would do is to just forward the outputs and handle them in the outer function.

```js
const innerFunction = async () => asyncFunction(false); // <-- Just return the outputs
const outerFunction = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await innerFunction(); // <-- Error is forwarded and thus handled
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Caught error inside outerFunction");
  }
};
```